# Call second Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, call

I want to call a second Activity from a ListViewActivity. I tried this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

but it doesnt work, maybee you can help me. Eclipse says this:

```
The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Activity2>) is undefined
```

I have also tried this with the same result.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity2.class);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, Activity2.class);
```

Comment: In your first code example, `this` is referring to the `OnItemClickListener`, not the parent Activity class.  As Arhimed shows, you need to use `YourCurrentActivity.this` instead to clarify which `this` you're trying to use.